# Relationship between classes when using LINQ to SQL (no relationship in the DB)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have two tables in my database -> Activities and Customers. Each Activity has a CustomerId, however the designers of the database haven't added any foreign key constraints.

I want to be able to write

```
activity.Customer.Name //Returns name of the customer
```

So I need a way of telling LINQ to SQL to map the CustomerId in the Activity object to the correct Customer object.

I could of course do :

```
var customers = db.Customers;
var activities = db.Activities;
```

And then manually map them to each other, but that would be a pain...

Is this is possible? Adding foreign key constraints is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: I think you may modify relations in the edmx, but these may be overwritten each time you update the model. Haven't test it.

Comment: What about using an AssociationAttribute?  Not sure if this requires the constraint to exist in the DB.  Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.associationattribute.isforeignkey(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write next two lines.

```
var customer = db.Customers.First(c => c.Id == activity.CustomerId);
var customerName = customer.Name;
```

One step further write an extension method

```
static Customer GetCustomer(this Activity)
{
    return db.Customers.First(c => c.Id == activity.CustomerId);
}
```

and use like

```
activity.GetCustomer().Name;
```